# a way to link xstate visualizer to react app

Tags: visualizer, xstate

I have a react app that uses xstate and there are lots of variables and services and everytime I would like to display it to the visualizer, I have to remove those variables. Is there a way to link xstate visualizer to my app? like when my app runs it also reflects in state visualizer. Thanks

Comment: Ask again in 3 days ;-)

Comment: @DavidKhourshid i think it has been more than three days :)

Comment: Check out `@xstate/inspect`: https://xstate.js.org/docs/packages/xstate-inspect

Comment: @DavidKhourshid docs for xstate-inspect are nowhere to be found. Also npm package link to the repo is 404.